# Installed dual boot: Goes straight to Windows, does not show option to Ubuntu

Tags: 12.10

**Translated:**

I had no trouble installing Ubuntu on a partition set as advanced in the process, but apparently the installation is incomplete because the restart does not give me the option to enter menu Windows7 or Linux. After trying several relocations in the stage of repair installed packages, the installation stops, and when I reboot, it does in windows7 as usual.

**Original:**

No he tenido problemas para instalar Ubuntu, en una partición que fije a medida que avancé en el proceso, pero aparentemente la instalación queda incompleta porque al reiniciar no me da el menú opcional para ingresar en Windows7 o en Linux. Después de intentar varias reinstalaciones en la etapa de reparación de paquetes ya instalados, se interrumpe la instalación, y cuando reinicio, lo hace en windows7 como normalmente.

Comment: Puedes iniciar sesión en Ubuntu? Qué pasa específicamente cuando prendes tu PC? (Can you boot into Ubuntu? What happens when you turn on your PC?)

Comment: Sujete shift cuando la computadora está reiniciando. Qué pasa? (Hold shift when the computer is rebooting. What happens?)